# PHP - Can't remove minutes from time

Tags: php, date, time

I have 3 variables storing times, they are as follows;

- $start_time_name = start time
- $end_time_name = end time
- $total_break_name = breaks

I can calculate the difference between start and end time, although it never takes into consideration the breaks (even though the break variable brings back the correct value)

```
$total_hours_work_cal = ($end_time_name - $total_break_name);
```

The calculation for this would be;

- End time = 10:00
- Start Time = 05:00
- Break Time = 00:30

But it just returns 05:00 as opposed to the expected 04:30

Any ideas? I've tried a lot of methods suggested by users on Stack Overflow, although to no avail.

**EDIT*

Edited to include more code;

```
  $start_time_name = $_POST['start_time_name'];
  $end_time_name = $_POST['end_time_name'];
  $total_break_name = $_POST['total_break_name'];

  $total_hours_work_cal = ($end_time_name - $total_break_name - $start_time_name) 
  * 60 * 60;

  echo "BEFORE CONVERSION" . $total_hours_work_cal;

  $total_hours_work_cal = gmdate("H:i:s", $total_hours_work_cal);

  echo "AFTER CONVERSION" . $total_hours_work_cal;
```

Comment: please show us the code.

Comment: I've made another edit @Max Muster

Comment: You are trying to do math with values that _aren’t_ numbers. `10:00 - 00:30 - 05:00` is not a valid mathematical operation. PHP is _forced_ to convert these string values into numbers first, and that is done by cutting off after at the first non-numeric character. The actual calculation that happens here is `10 - 0 - 5`, and the result of that _of course_ is `5`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation CBroe, appreciated - although how do I get around this?

Comment: Are you receiving dates from form like this 10:00, 05:00 etc?

Comment: Correct @TufailAhmad

Comment: The best way is to use timestamp. You should study timestamp in PHP. You can convert dates to timestamp and can take date and time differences through PHP built-in functions.

Comment: I've used strtotime() and it doesn't return the expected result still

Comment: can you show the code which you have tried through strtotime?

Answer (score 1):

```
function hoursandmins($time, $format = '%02d:%02d'){
    if ($time < 1) {
        return;
    }
    $hours = floor($time / 60);
    $minutes = ($time % 60);
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}

$start_time_name    = "05:00";
$end_time_name  = "10:00";
$total_break_name   = "30"; //in minutes

$start_time_name = strtotime($start_time_name);
$end_time_name   = strtotime($end_time_name);
$total_break_name = (int) $total_break_name * 60; //convert into seconds

$total_hours_work_cal = $end_time_name - $total_break_name - $start_time_name; //total time will be in seconds
$total_hours_work_cal = $total_hours_work_cal / 60; //converted into minutes;

$total_hours_work_cal = hoursandmins($total_hours_work_cal); //convert into hours and minutes
echo $total_hours_work_cal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*

$total_hours_work_cal = ($end_time_name - $total_break_name);

The calculation for this would be;

    End time = 10:00
    Start Time = 05:00
    Break Time = 00:30
*/

$start = new \DateTime('05:00:00');
$end = new \DateTime('10:00:00');
$break = new \DateInterval('PT30M');

$beginEndInterval = $end->diff($start);

$total = new \DateTime('00:00');
$totalComp = new \DateTime('00:00');
$total->add($beginEndInterval);
$total->add($break);
echo $totalComp->diff($total)->format('%H:%I'); // 04:30
```

Comment: please consider to add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
/* justfor testing purpose to have input */

$_POST['start_time_name'] = "05:00";
$_POST['total_break_name'] = "00:30";
$_POST['end_time_name'] = "10:00";


$start_time_name = $_POST['start_time_name'];
$end_time_name = $_POST['end_time_name'];
$total_break_name = $_POST['total_break_name'];

$end_time = mktime(explode(":",$end_time_name)[0],explode(":",$end_time_name)[1]);
$start_time = mktime(explode(":",$start_time_name)[0],explode(":",$start_time_name)[1]);
$total_break = mktime(explode(":",$total_break_name)[0],explode(":",$total_break_name)[1]);

$diff = $end_time + $total_break - $start_time;

$total_hours_work_cal = date("H:i",$diff);

echo "TOTAL HOURS OF WORK : " . $total_hours_work_cal;

// TOTAL HOURS OF WORK : 05:30
```